# How to format string in Java when the value goes from parameters?

Tags: java, regex, string, stringbuilder

I have a problem: I need to get a phone number as a string "79991111111" and convert it to this type of string "+7 (999) 111-11-11".

As i got it i'm able to do it by using a String.format() - but in this case I need a string initially, but i know only format of expected string that comes by parameters (ex. "79991111111"), but not the exact string.

**Summary**: I need do "+7 (999) 111-11-11" from "79991111111" and there is difference values all the time, but the same type and length.

I tried to do it via regex, but i don't know how to change string with using regex

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others. Included sources [should be in text format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5043481), not an image. Currently you are not asking any question.

Comment: If you use regular expressions, be careful about international prefixes: In your example, the prefix is just one digit long ("7"), but you must take in account that there are two-digit and even three-digit prefixes. To solve that, you might prepend zeroes at the begginning to fix the input string length to 13.

Comment: Adding to what @LittleSanti said, the "+7" in this example is a country calling code. Not only can the length of the country calling code vary (eg: +7 vs  +44 vs +592), but the length and format of the number that comes after it also depends on the country code in use (eg: +1 uses the format "+1 (XXX) XXX-XXXX" while +86 uses the format "+86 XXX XXXX XXXX").

Answer (score 4):

Make use of [`MaskFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html), for example...

```
MaskFormatter mf = new MaskFormatter("+# (###) ###-##-##");
mf.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
System.out.println(mf.valueToString("79991111111"));
```

which will output `+7 (999) 111-11-11`

## Update

You should take a look at [Googles libphonenumber](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber) - as formatting phone numbers does not have a simple solution

*(ps - I've never used this before, this is all experimental on my part)*

So, based on the documented examples, you could do something like...

```
// I had to add the `+` prefix, otherwise the parsing would fail
String input = "+79991111111";
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
    Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse(input, CountryCodeSource.UNSPECIFIED.name());
    System.out.println(phoneNumber);
    System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL));
    System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL));
    System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.E164));
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
    System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```

And this will print ...

```
+7 999 111-11-11
8 (999) 111-11-11
+79991111111
```

At this point you "should" be able to walk away, as these are using "standardised" formats, but, if you need to do something "special", you could make use of `PhoneNumberUtil#formatByPattern`, which might look something like...

```
String input = "+79991111111";
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
    NumberFormat newNumFormat = new NumberFormat();
    newNumFormat.setPattern("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})");
    newNumFormat.setFormat("($1) $2-$3-$4");

    List<NumberFormat> newNumberFormats = new ArrayList<NumberFormat>();
    newNumberFormats.add(newNumFormat);

    String formatted = phoneUtil.formatByPattern(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL, newNumberFormats);
    System.out.println(formatted);
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
    System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```

and output something like...

```
+7 (999) 111-11-11
```

which, again, is probably as close as you will get.

Please also remember, formatting phone numbers is not simple as there are no real "standard" rules across all countries ... it's a mess

Comment: maybe related to the country code.... just  a guess

Comment: @user16320675 Based on the available input and desired output, this works - they weren’t asking about phone numbers  ‍♂️

Comment: I know it works... and how "they weren’t asking about phone numbers" ?? They wrote "I need to get a phone number" - I believe the downvotes on all answers are because of the country code (`+7`) of given sample number (again, just my guess... people have reason to not help that country)

Comment: @user16320675 Yeah, I probably skimmed over that part - my bad 

Answer (score 2):

You can use capturing groups and then replace the string as the desired pattern.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "(\\d)(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})";
        // Test
        Stream.of(
                "79991111111",
                "12345678901"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.replaceAll(regex,"+$1($2)$3-$4-$5")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
+7(999)111-11-11
+1(234)567-89-01
```

**Notes:**

1. There are 5 capturing groups in the regex pattern and each of them has been used with its position as a replaceable parameter in the replacement string.
2. `\d` represents a single digit and `\d{3}` represents three digits in the regex pattern.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/elej4P/1)

Answer (score 1):

> *'... I need to get a phone number as a string "79991111111" and convert it to this type of string "+7 (999) 111-11-11". ...'*

You can use the *[StringBuilder#insert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,char))* method to insert a character into a *String* value.

```java
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder("79991111111");
string.insert(0, '+');
string.insert(2, " (");
string.insert(7, ") ");
string.insert(12, '-');
string.insert(15, '-');
```

Output

```
+7 (999) 111-11-11
```

Or, you could use a *[String#substring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int))* for each part of the value.

```java
String string = "79991111111";
String[] strings = {
    string.substring(0, 1),
    string.substring(1, 4),
    string.substring(4, 7),
    string.substring(7, 9),
    string.substring(9)
};
string = "+%s (%s) %s-%s-%s".formatted(strings);
```

Output

```
+7 (999) 111-11-11
```

> *"... I tried to do it via regex, but i don't know how to change string with using regex"*

You can use the *[String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))* method to capture each group of numbers, and insert values between them.

Since the value will always be the same length, you can use the *wildcard* character `.`, and capture syntax `( )`.

```java
String string = "79991111111".replaceAll("(.)(...)(...)(..)(..)", "+$1 ($2) $3-$4-$5");
```